# Width of Sprite image adjusted to Ajax generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, sprite

I have a form button that has a sprite image as background.  It works fine with all content EXCEPT if the content is loaded via AJAX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting an id say `<button type="button" id="foo">Click Me!</button>` and put the css within the content that is loaded using ajax.

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    #foo
    {
        background: transparent url('http://foo.com/images/sprites.png') no-repeat fixed 0px 0px;
    }
/*]]>*/
</style>
```